# Class based object instances for state in NGXS

Tags: angular, ngxs

[NGXS Style Guide](https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/style-guide#avoid-saving-class-based-instances-in-your-state) has a point:

> It is not recommended to add Class based object instances to your state because this can lead to undefined behavior in the future.

e.g.

```
//== This is NOT recommended:
ctx.setState((state: Todo[]) => state.concat(new Todo(action.title)));

//== This is recommended
state.concat({ title: action.title, isCompleted: false })
```

Why creating class instance with `new` is not recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because those created objects have multiple properties, like functions, constructor, maybe private properties
and so on ...
you dont want to save those properties too!

You should have an export-function in your Todo-class:

```js
interface TodoModel {
  /* your properties you want to take care of! */
}

class Todo implements TodoModel {
  export(): TodoModel {
  }

  import(model: TodoModel) {
  }
}
```